# Changing the browser that urlretrieve specifies

Tags: urllib, python-3.3

I am using urlretrieve to download some stuff.

What browser does it specify when making requests, and how can I change it?

N.B.  I am using Python 3.3,  The documentation is here:

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request

Comment: Do you mean what user agent does it send?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [`urllib.request.Request`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request), it says that the default User Agent should be `"Python-urllib/3.3"` if you're using Python 3.3. This can be changed by setting [`urllib.request.URLopener.version`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.URLopener.version). Note that this is deprecated since Python 3.3.

---

If you're looking for an HTTP library that's a lot easier to use, check out [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org). It's **so** much easier than using `urllib` or `urllib2`.